Connect Next Js website to a .NET API using Windows Authentication
I have an internal website running .net 8 with windows authentication, containing an api. The api uses windows impersonation to retrieve information from other internal services. I would like to consume said api from a new website running Next Js (14), but keep the SSO functionality (no login prompts) that we get from the current setup where we use an MVC website.
Doing this client side works great using include credentials true, but I´m struggling to get this working when server side rendering.
The problem is I cannot get NodeJs to act on the WWW-Authenticate Negotiate header sent from the api.
I started looking at npm packages, for example node-sspi and node-expose-sspi, but they all seem rather obsolete(?). Does anyone have a working setup using an npm package (or self made implementation) that they could recommend?
I also tried setting up a reverse proxy for the frontend website (using yarp and iis), running windows auth and passing the negotiate token through the Next JS site and on to the api, but I couldn´t get it to work so I guess the token is only valid for the actual reverse proxy in said scenario?
I also tried signing in using windows authentication on the reverse proxy and setting a cookie with the claimsidentity and reading the cookie on the api server. This works well for the claims part, but I am unable to cast the claims identity to a windows identity for impersonation, so that also seems to be a dead end.
Does anyone have a working setup for a similar scenario? Any advice is much appreciated.
